# Remove duplicate dates for each level of another variable

Tags: r

I have a dataframe and I want to remove the duplicate values of the "Date" column based on the levels of the "Code" column. I would prefer to avoid data.table. Thank you.

```
Date           Code
 20120301       boy
 20120607       boy
 20130910       girl
 20120301       boy
 20120301       girl
 20090808       girl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df[!duplicated(paste0(df$Date, df$Code)),]
#      Date Code
#1 20120301  boy
#2 20120607  boy
#3 20130910 girl
#5 20120301 girl
#6 20090808 girl
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit suggestion and answer. This is what I wanted!